# Добавление в корзину и обновление страницы

Tags: php

учусь php и сейчас реализовываю на нем интернет-магазин. Почитал в интернете, как лучше реализовать кнопку добавления и там везде был такой вариант:

```
<input type="submit" name="buy" value="В корзину">
```

И потом с помощью `$_POST['buy']` доставать данные. Все сделал, все работает, но мне не нравится, что при нажатии на кнопку, страница обновляется и поднимается на вверх, тем самым доставляя неудобство покупателю. Может, пожалуйста, кто-нибудь предложить хороший вариант решения такой проблемы?

Comment: [Введение в AJAX](https://javascript.ru/ajax/intro)

Comment: @Doofy вполне нормальный вопрос. Не знаю, что там у вас за "серия" такая.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов не согласен. Правилами сайта предусмотрено задавать вопрос с минимальным примером и конктретный. А здесь слишком общий вопрос о реализации, где можно применить несколько подходов

Comment: @Doofy конкретная проблема - обновляется страница при нажатии, конкретный вопрос - как лучше решить? Или может другую реализацию использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Почитай про технологию AJAX:

> AJAX, Ajax (ˈeɪdʒæks, от англ. Asynchronous Javascript and XML —
> «асинхронный JavaScript и XML») — подход к построению интерактивных
> пользовательских интерфейсов веб-приложений, заключающийся в «фоновом»
> обмене данными браузера с веб-сервером. В результате при обновлении
> данных веб-страница не перезагружается полностью, и веб-приложения
> становятся быстрее и удобнее.

Comment: не стоит приучит к жирквери, на закате его успеха ) пусть лучше сразу ванильным скриптом делает )

Comment: @АлексДанилин причем тут jquery?

Comment: да чет глюкнул ). Вечно ассоциация идет с жирквери, Соря)

Comment: Спасибо большое!